# Relationship between RAM and CPU to assign to servers

Tags: linux, cpu, hardware, ram, resources

I would like to know if there is any method, formula, recommendation or good practice to establish the relationship between CPU and RAM on a server, be it physical or virtual, I have recently seen virtual machines (VMWare vSphere 6.5) that had assigned a quantity of CPU to my seem disproportionate, example a vm with 32 GB of RAM and 26 CPU, another with 16 GB RAM and 8 CPU, I am not clear how these resources should be allocated, could you please clarify if there is any way to calculate it or some method to assign them?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Software will require an amount of RAM to run and will need a certain amount of CPU to perform efficiently.

A virtual machine would need to be assigned the correct amount of RAM and CPU based on what software you plan on running with it.  Some software wants lots of CPU but can get away with little RAM, others want lots of RAM but do not need much CPU.

You should be able to change either RAM or CPU without affecting the other.  There is no direct, proportional relationship between RAM and CPU on a machine.